# XML C++ library for simple messages

Tags: c++, xml, sockets

I need a XML library for constructing simple XML messages. I come from a Java background. I've found some suggestions pointing at Xerces-C++ XML library as it was transferred.

Other suggested libraries have their advantages in memory in speed, but all of this is none of my needs. I need an API which supports an easy construction.

Furthermore I would like to ask when sending XML via sockets, do I have to pay attention on serialization or can I send plain xml texts?

Overall the focus is on building xml and none parsing at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple XML library would be TinyXML, see http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/tutorial0.html for an example (under section 'Building Documents Programatically')

edit:

If the XML is really simple, you can also just output the XML tags from your code. Something like:

```
std::stringstream s;
s << "<tag>" << var << "</tag>\n";
std::cout << s.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion [tinyxml](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/) Excellent performance and easy to use.
Usage : [TinyXML Tutorial](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/tutorial0.html)
or [libtinyxml](https://code.google.com/p/libtinyxml/) The TinyXML library provided with a CMake Build System.

Answer (score 0):

[RapidXML](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/)

> RapidXml is an attempt to create the fastest XML parser possible, while retaining useability, portability and reasonable W3C compatibility.

You will build your XML file in RAM, and at any time you can convert it to a string and from that, an array of chars, meaning you will send the XML file as an array of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [pugixml](https://github.com/zeux/pugixml) library is [fastest](http://pugixml.org/benchmark.html) though fullyfunctional, object-oriented C++ library, with support of XPath queries.